# How to use NSObject properties

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

So I have an `NSObject` called `Account` with some variables in it. I've added getter and setter methods in the class, but when I try to set the values and call get them I get nil.

```
import UIKit


class Account: NSObject {

    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""


    //setters
    func setNameFirst(newName: String){
        firstName = newName
    }

    func setNameLast(newName: String){
       lastName = newName
    }

    //getters
    func getFirstName() -> String{
       return firstName
    }

    func getLastName() -> String{
       return lastName
    }

}
```

In another view controller I try to set and print one of the variables.

```
import UIKit

var test: Account?

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        test?.setNameFirst("John")
        print(test?.getFirstName())
    }

}
```

but I get `nil` when it prints.

Comment: You never created an `Account` object.  You need to do `test = Account()` at some point.

Comment: You shouldn't be manually adding setters and getters.  You can get/set the properties by doing `test?.firstName = "John"` and `print(test.firstName)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `test` as an optional `Account` --- that's what `Account?` is.

Given that you never initialized it to anything it will remain `nil` and prints `nil`.

To correct this you will need to add (as vacawama said in the comments):

```
test = Account() // test no longer nil
```

Now `test` will be an instance of `Account` instead of `nil`.

**Additional example, in a playground:**

```
let test : Account?
print(test) // won't run
```

but

```
let test : Account?
test = Account()
print(test) // prints an instance of Account
```

**Also, your getters and setters are redundant.**

Doing this:

```
let test = Account()
test.firstName = "First"
print(test.firstName) // prints "First\n"
```

is the same as:

```
let test = Account()
test.setNameFirst("First")
print(test.getFirstName()) // prints "First\n"
```

Comment: That explains it! Thanks a ton